# LG 34WQ75X-B brightness issue and USB-C disconnects with battery

Tags: mac, brightness, lg-monitor

I have quite recently bought LG 34WQ75X-B.AEU and generally found it ok in terms of price/quality perspective. Currently I have connected my Mac M1 with it. The issue is that, although at the Mac, the options "True Tone" and "Automatically adjust brightness" options are turned off, the external monitor behaves as if it is trying to adapt to the ambient's light, and does some low level darkening and lightening which distrupts my focus while working. I am already not a fan of such automatically adjustable lightening options. Do you guys think is it something to do with Mac or some sort of a "bug" with the monitor itself? And with that do you think shall I return it only because of that?

There is one thing, the external monitor time to time loses the battery connection with the laptop but still keeps the display on. I read lots of comments that says it is a very common thing in the external monitors, therefore I am not very sure should I consider this as a "return factor".

Finally, there is this Display Link dialog at the top of my toolbar which I am not sure what it expects from me and whether does it anything to do with the above issues.

[image]

I would appreciate for any comment since I am right now going back and forth with the idea of returning the monitor, which without the brightness issue specifically, I would be ok to keep it, but dont know.

Comment: DisplayLink Manager is a 3rd party app, not Apple. Check with them  https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1932214-displaylink-manager-app-for-macos-introduction-in or try without it.